# Nginx how to redirect index.php

Tags: nginx

I have wp installed in a sub-directory named cms inside the pub folder (pub/cms/) of my magento 2 install. When I type domain.com/cms/index.php it serves a page without the theme. It is just text and images. What would be the correct nginx redirect to redirect domain.com/cms/index.php page to domain.com/blog.

I would like the redirect to be compatible with yoast's sitemap which is being served under the following dir which I cannot figure out how to change:
domain.com/cms/index.php/sitemap_index.xml

I tried several different nginx commands but was met with failure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wait, so is WP under `example.com/cms/` or `example.com/blog/`? Can't you change the folder structure?

Comment: WP is installed under pub/cms/  and using the Fishpig extension for magento/wp the base url is set to /blog. When I type https://domain.com/blog I get the post list with the theme included, but when I type https://domain.com/index.php it renders raw text. I am trying to avoid duplicate content here.